# Google maps removing previous marker location tracking

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to display marker on user position and remove the previous one.I have tried something like this but its not working.

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
         String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         Marker playermarker = null;
         if (playermarker!=null) {
              playermarker.remove();
              playermarker=null;
         }

         if (playermarker==null) {
              playermarker = googleMap.addMarker(new 
                    MarkerOptions().position(new 
                    LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude())));
         }
      }

      public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
};
```

Comment: When the location is changed, you are creating a new object everytime. Try creating the marker object outside of `onLocationChanged` method.

Comment: Ofcourse you could also use playermarker.setPosition() with the new position without removing and recreating.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
  onLocationChanged{

       if (currLocationMarker != null) {
                currLocationMarker.remove();
            }

            latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Position.......");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            currLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```

**Custom Marker** select image form **drawable folder**

```
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
```

Comment: hello when i try to add custom marker with .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.raw.custommarker))   its not working do  you know why

Comment: @ip879 you have put you image in your drawable folder...then use like **icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.custommarker))**